# A mesh points for each polygon: how to create function?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, function

I want to use function for creating a mesh point for each polygon, but I am new in python.

what is wrong with the function:

```py
def creatingPoints(minX, minY,maxX,maxY,number):
    while minY < maxY:
        minX = ext.XMin
        maxX = ext.XMax
        X.append(minX) # start from minY
        Y.append(minY)
        while minX < maxX:
            X.append(minX)
            Y.append(minY)
            minX += number
        minY += number
    return
```

This function did not work:

```py
import arcpy # csv
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

print "Creating and defining variables."
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Desktop\data"

#Define Function:
#global minX, maxX, minY, maxY 
def creatingPoints(minX, minY,maxX,maxY,number):
     while minY < maxY:
         minX = ext.XMin
         maxX = ext.XMax
         X.append(minX) # start from minY
         Y.append(minY)
         while minX < maxX:
             X.append(minX)
             Y.append(minY)
             minX += number
         minY += number
     return 

Curs = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(theme,  ["OID@", "SHAPE@"])
for row in Curs:
# Print the current polygon's ID
    print("Feature {}:".format(row[0]))

    for pnt in row[1]:
        polygon = Curs[1]
        ext = polygon.extent
 # Find min X, Y and max X, Y for each polygon and write it to the file:
        print 'xmin is: ', ext.XMin
        print 'ymin is: ', ext.YMin
        print 'xmax is: ', ext.XMax
        print 'ymax is: ', ext.YMax             
 # create row of points for 1 polygon
        if row[0] == 0:
            X1 = []
            Y1 = []
            minX = ext.XMin
            minY = ext.YMin
            maxX = ext.XMax
            maxY = ext.YMax

            number = 2000
          # Call function           
            creatingPoints(minX, minY,maxX,maxY,number)
            print "The List of X1coordinates: "
            print X1
            print "The List of Y1coordinates: "
            print Y1

      # create row of points for 2 polygon           
        if row[0] == 1:
            X2 = []
            Y2 = []
            minX = ext.XMin
            minY = ext.YMin
            maxX = ext.XMax
            maxY = ext.YMax

            number = 3500
          # Call function           
            creatingPoints(minX, minY,maxX,maxY,number)
            print "The List of X_coordinates: "
            print X2
            print "The List of Y_coordinates: "
            print Y2   

         # create row of points for 3 polygon
        if row[0] == 2:
            X3 = []
            Y3 = []
            minX = ext.XMin
            minY = ext.YMin
            maxX = ext.XMax
            maxY = ext.YMax

            number = 4500
        # Call function           
            creatingPoints(minX, minY,maxX,maxY,number)
            print "The List of X_coordinates: "
            print X3
            print "The List of Y_coordinates: "
            print Y3   

X = X1 + X2 + X3
Y = Y1 + Y2 + Y3


print "The List of X_coordinates: "
print X
print "The List of Y_coordinates: "
print Y

coords = zip(X, Y)
print "The List of zip(X, Y)  " 
print coords*
```

The output did not give me list of  coordinates:

```
Creating and defining variables.
Feature 0:
xmin is:  545008.083489
ymin is:  4446123.0101
xmax is:  587780.363465
ymax is:  4490824.55127
The List of X1coordinates: 
[]
The List of Y1coordinates: 
[]
Feature 1:
xmin is:  479147.831799
ymin is:  4410452.25357
xmax is:  533670.087568
ymax is:  4465090.21701
The List of X_coordinates: 
[]
The List of Y_coordinates: 
[]
Feature 2:
xmin is:  546366.4017
ymin is:  4392176.42464
xmax is:  587670.483369
ymax is:  4426111.19118
The List of X_coordinates: 
[]
The List of Y_coordinates: 
[]
The List of X_coordinates: 
[]
The List of Y_coordinates: 
[]
The List of zip(X, Y)  
[]
```

---

At first code looks like this:
(*but I need to improve this with function createPoints*)

```py
import arcpy # csv
from arcpy import env

print "Creating and defining variables."
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\anna_pavlenko\Desktop\data"
env.overwriteOutput = 1

theme = 'interestAreas.shp' 
# Look for .next()  in SearchCursor, need a loop
# the same when we read line by line


Curs = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(theme,  ["OID@", "SHAPE@"])
for row in Curs:
   # Print the current polygon's ID
    #
    print("Feature {}:".format(row[0]))

    for pnt in row[1]:
        polygon = Curs[1]
        ext = polygon.extent
# Find min X, Y and max X, Y for each polygon and write it to the file:
        print 'xmin is: ', ext.XMin
        print 'ymin is: ', ext.YMin
        print 'xmax is: ', ext.XMax
        print 'ymax is: ', ext.YMax               
# create row of points for 1 polygon

        if row[0] == 0:
            X1 = []
            Y1 = []
            minY = ext.YMin
            maxY = ext.YMax
            while minY < maxY:

                minX = ext.XMin
                maxX = ext.XMax

                X1.append(minX) # start from minY
                Y1.append(minY)

                while minX < maxX: # create 1 line of point through the line X  till minX < maxX, Y = constant              
                    X1.append(minX)  # start from minX
                    Y1.append(minY)
                    minX += 2000.0
                minY += 2000.0  #increase Y by 2000 m and start new row     
            print "The List of X_coordinates: "
            print X1
            print "The List of Y_coordinates: "
            print Y1
# create row of points for 2 polygon

        if row[0] == 1:
            X2 = []
            Y2 = []
            minY = ext.YMin
            maxY = ext.YMax
            while minY < maxY:
                minX = ext.XMin
                maxX = ext.XMax

                X2.append(minX) # start from minY
                Y2.append(minY)

                while minX < maxX: # create 1 line of point through the line X  till minX < maxX, Y = constant              
                    X2.append(minX)  # start from minX
                    Y2.append(minY)
                    minX += 3500.0
                minY += 3500.0  #increase Y by 2000 m and start new row
            print "The List of X_coordinates: "
            print X2
            print "The List of Y_coordinates: "
            print Y2                


# create row of points for 3 polygon
        if row[0] == 2:
            X3 = []
            Y3 = []
            minY = ext.YMin
            maxY = ext.YMax
            while minY < maxY:
                minX = ext.XMin
                maxX = ext.XMax

                X3.append(minX) # start from minY
                Y3.append(minY)

                while minX < maxX: # create 1 line of point through the line X  till minX < maxX, Y = constant              
                    X3.append(minX)  # start from minX
                    Y3.append(minY)
                    minX += 4500.0
                minY += 4500.0  #increase Y by 2000 m and start new row
            print "The List of X_coordinates: "
            print X3
            print "The List of Y_coordinates: "
            print Y3
X = X1 + X2 + X3
Y = Y1 + Y2 + Y3


print "The List of X_coordinates: "
print X
print "The List of Y_coordinates: "
print Y

coords = zip(X, Y)
print "The List of zip(X, Y)  " 
print coords
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please be aware that while we are happy to help with code snippets we do not offer a code debugging service.  Would you be able to extract a code snippet that shows where what you expect to happen starts to deviate from what you observe to happen, please?

Comment: I'm confused by your inclusion of a second large block of code which looks like it may be the same as the first large block of code.  In between it looks like your output but which block of code was run to produce that?  Assuming one large block of code is not needed would you be able to improve your question by editing the other one out, please?